# How do I make a table that has a set number of columns in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multiple-columns

My problem is that I want to have the number of rows increase automatically but I am not sure how to set the number of columns for the table in javascript.

```
var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
for (i = 0; i < dataResponse.length; i++) {
    createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');
}
```

**So how do I set the number of columns for a table in Javascript?**

Comment: Why dont you just append it to body? .append(html)?

Comment: `dataResponse.length` should be the number of entries / rows, i'm guessing. Now, what is `dataResponse`? Where are you getting it from? What's inside it?

Comment: can you share a working implementation else it would leads to a XY propblem

Comment: @EduardoEscobar the dataResponse is a set of data that I have my javascript linked to. it has arrays of data and my question is that in javascript how would I set the number of columns. The code up there is just to show that I am setting the number of rows to adjust as the data in the set changes.

Comment: @AleksandarĐokić would the appending to body be able to append multiple columns at a time? Or would it only append one columns at a time?

Comment: @VigneshRaja what do you mean? do you need an example?

Comment: Yeah. We can assume the `dataResponse` as array of arrays of data / array of objects with key as table heading and values as cell content which may mislead you.

Comment: `dataResponse[i].length` *should* be the number of columns of the current row, in case `dataResponse[i]` is an array, if it's an object, `Object.keys(dataResponse[i]).length` is the way to go. Of course, i can't tell if ALL your rows have the same amount of columns.

Comment: @VigneshRaja here is the setup for dataResponse

Comment: @VigneshRaja
    {   "issues": [
  {
   "id": "45468",
   "key": "PR-1968",
   "fields": {
    "timetracking": {
     "originalEstimate": "13h",
     "remainingEstimate": "13h",
     }
  {
   "id": "45468",
   "key": "PR-1968",
   "fields": {
    "timetracking": {
     "originalEstimate": "13h",
     "remainingEstimate": "13h",
     }
      }
 ]}

Comment: @EduardoEscobar all of my rows have the same amount of columns with this information:     {   "issues": [
  {
   "key": "PR-1968",
   "fields": {
    "timetracking": {
     "originalEstimate": "13h",
     "remainingEstimate": "13h",
     }
  {
   "key": "PR-1968",
   "fields": {
    "timetracking": {
     "originalEstimate": "13h",
     "remainingEstimate": "13h",
     }
      }
 ]}

Comment: @Nicole M, your JSON is malformed.

Comment: A context is necessary for solving your problem. What is the createCell function? When are you running this procedure? What is the difference of the current outcome from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. For inner tables, the logic need to be re-written.

```js
var data = { "issues": [ { "id": "45468", "key": "PR-1968", "fields": { "timetracking": { "originalEstimate": "13h", "remainingEstimate": "13h" }}}, { "id": "45468", "key": "PR-1968", "fields": { "timetracking": { "originalEstimate": "13h", "remainingEstimate": "13h" }}} ]};

function createElement(tagname,content)
{
    var elem = document.createElement(tagname);
    elem.innerHTML = content;
    return elem;
}

function createTable()
{
    var columnnames = Object.keys(data.issues[0]);
    
    var tableheading = "";
    columnnames.forEach(function(columnname){
        tableheading += createElement("th",columnname).outerHTML;
    });
    tableheading = createElement("tr",tableheading).outerHTML;
    
    var tabledata = "";
    data.issues.forEach(function(obj){
        var tablerow = "";
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
            var cell = createElement("td",JSON.stringify(obj[key]));
            tablerow += cell.outerHTML;
        });
        tablerow = createElement("tr",tablerow);
        tabledata += tablerow.outerHTML;
    });
    
    return createElement("table",tableheading+tabledata);
}

document.body.appendChild(createTable())
```

```css
table, tr, th, td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```